# Dependency Injection not Occurring in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I have a controller, `ApiBundle\Controller\UserController`, and it has the following contents:

```
<?php
namespace ApiBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use ApiBundle\Form\RegisterType;
use ApiBundle\Utility\ApiUtility;

class UserController extends ApiController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * UserController constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("register")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function registerUser(Request $request)
    {
        $data = ApiUtility::getContentAsArray($request);

        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $user);

        $form->submit($data);
        if($form->isValid()) {
            $user->setUsername($request->get('email'));
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush();
        }else{
            return ApiUtility::returnResponse($form->getErrors());
        }
    }
}
```

It extends API Controller, seen here:

```
<?php
namespace ApiBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;


class ApiController extends FOSRestController
{
}
```

And it has the following services:

```
services:
    api.controller.user:
        class: ApiBundle\Controller\UserController
        public: false
        parent: api.controller
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]

    api.controller:
        class: ApiBundle\Controller\ApiController
        calls:
         - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

No matter what I do, I can't get the container to inject.  Right now, when I just try to get doctrine into the container through the constructor, I get `Type error: Too few arguments to function ApiBundle\Controller\UserController::__construct(), 0 passed in app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2230 and exactly 1 expected`, if I switch it back to $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager') or getEntityManager, I get container is null.  How can I fix this?

Comment: `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` returns null?

Comment: what is the reason in your case to define your Controller as a Service? You can do that but I don't see a reason. @MaxP. 's answer is right in any case, you should not inject EntityManager even if you define your Controller as a Service.

Comment: Defining controllers as services is fine.  The problem is in your routing.  You need to specify that the controller is a service: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html#referring-to-the-service And I am pretty sure you will need to remove the public: false line.